# error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'ElementRef<any>'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have this problem:

error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'ElementRef'.

I have a .html file with this code:

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-input placeholder="Enter Name" type="text" #name name="name" ></ion-input>
  <ion-input placeholder="Enter Surname" type="text" #surname name="surname" ></ion-input>
  <ion-input placeholder="Enter Type" type="text" #type name="type" ></ion-input>
  <ion-button (click)="addNewUser()">Add New User</ion-button>
```

and a file .ts with this code:

```js
export class FirstPage implements OnInit {

  springUsers: SpringUser[];
  @ViewChild('name') name: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('surname') surname: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('type') type: ElementRef;
  
  ///[...]
  
  
  addNewUser(){
    console.log('addNewUser');
    let tempUser: SpringUser;
    tempUser = {
      name: this.name.value,
      surname: this.surname.value,
      type: this.type.value,
      email: 'email@gmail.com',
      password: '',
      passwordToVerify: ''

    } ;

    tempUser.name = this.name.value;
    tempUser.surname = this.surname.value;
    tempUser.type = this.type.value;

    this.springUserService.postSpringUser(tempUser).subscribe(data => {
      console.log('inserted user', data);
    });
```

Comment: Try `this.name.nativeElement.value` as per the doc (https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef#properties). That basically applies to all your `ElementRef` calls.

Comment: Add an `[(ngModel)]` to each input ?

Comment: Now the program compiled but i have this problem:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at FirstPage.addNewUser (first.page.ts:33) 

where: first.page.ts:33 is:

addNewUser(){
    console.log('addNewUser');
    let tempUser: SpringUser;
    tempUser = {
      name: this.name.nativeElement.value, // line 33
      surname: this.surname.nativeElement.value,
      type: this.type.nativeElement.value,
      email: 'email@gmail.com',
      password: '',
      passwordToVerify: ''

    } ;

Answer (score 3):

Try `this.name.nativeElement.value` as per the docs ([docs](http://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef#properties)). That basically applies to all your `ElementRef` calls.